# How to rank users with coefficient data in mysql?

Tags: mysql, database

In a game, I have a list of users which data are recorded in a table called "ranks". Those users win points day after day and for each day they have a new record in the table ranks. But, some days are more important than others, and the points could pay more. For technical reasons, I had to store initial points in the database. So I added a new field "coefficient" and I have to calculate total points on the fly.

For example, those users :

```
user,   points,     day,    coefficient
user 1, 35 points,  day 1,  coefficient 1
user 1, 20 points,  day 2,  coefficient 1
user 1, 15 points,  day 3,  coefficient 2

user 2, 40 points,  day 1,  coefficient 1
user 2, 35 points,  day 2,  coefficient 1
user 2,  5 points,  day 3,  coefficient 2
```

I would like to calculate points for all the days, for each day or for several days in a same time. My query seems to be wrong for several days:

```
$sql = 'SELECT (SUM(r.points) * r.coefficient) AS total 
        FROM ranks AS r 
        GROUP BY user 
        ORDER BY total DESC ';
$sql = 'SELECT (SUM(r.points) * r.coefficient) AS total 
        FROM ranks AS r 
        WHERE day IN (2,3) 
        ORDER BY total DESC ';
```

I have some difficulties to format the second query to work correctly.

Thanks all!

Alexander

Comment: Probably because your `day` column contains the word `day` in `day 2` and therefore your `IN (2,3)` wont find anything. ___Or does it?___

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you are taking the sum of the points and multiplying that with the cofficient (which in practice means you are first summing all the points and then multiplying that sum with an arbitrary cofficient). You want to take the sum of each point multiplied with each cofficient first, before taking the sum of these numbers.

Also, you would want to include the user in the select, as this is what you are grouping on (I think -- it might work without, but this is what I am used to doing).

Try this:

```
$sql = 'SELECT user, SUM(r.points * r.coefficient) AS total 
    FROM ranks r
    WHERE day IN (2,3) 
    GROUP BY user 
    ORDER BY total DESC ';
```